# Is there any way to make list-group vertical on big screens and horizontal on small?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I need horizontal list group on small screen sizes, but the only solution I can find is opposite to that. The way list-group-horizontal works - vertical on small screens and horizontal when screen grows. What can I do in such situation? I tried to create 2 different list groups but they don't work together.

Comment: You could invert the rules... but why would you want to? If you've got more than about two items, you'll need to scroll on a mobile in a horizontal layout.

Comment: Can I? I need it because this is in design layout that I have. Vertical list-group with naming and horizontal with just numbers (1-7) on mobile. That is what I have to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Vertical on large screen and Horizontal on small screen

By default, list-group's **flex-direction** is `column`. You just need to set it to `row` for small screens and then reset it to `column` for large screen. In order to to do so, use **`flex-*-column`** and **`flex-row`** .

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col mt-5">
      <ul class="list-group flex-sm-column flex-row">
        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gJxBLP

---

### Vertical on small screen and Horizontal on large screen

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col mt-5">
      <ul class="list-group flex-column flex-sm-row">
        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KLvGNX

---

I have used `flex-sm-*`. You may need to use `flex-md-*` or `flex-lg-*`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native class in Bootstrap for this behaviour. But it is easy to create one using SASS:

```
@include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
  .list-group-horizontal-sm-down {
    flex-direction: row;

    .list-group-item {
      &:first-child {
        @include border-bottom-left-radius($list-group-border-radius);
        @include border-top-right-radius(0);
      }

      &:last-child {
        @include border-top-right-radius($list-group-border-radius);
        @include border-bottom-left-radius(0);
      }

      &.active {
        margin-top: 0;
      }

      & + .list-group-item {
        border-top-width: $list-group-border-width;
        border-left-width: 0;

        &.active {
          margin-left: -$list-group-border-width;
          border-left-width: $list-group-border-width;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a basic example of usage:

```html
<ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal-sm-down">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

Reference: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/scss/_list-group.scss#L93